# how to run docker image with iptables support enabled?

Tags: docker, networking, containers, iptables, docker-network

I have these two containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
0d671dfac62b        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         38 minutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                       firewall-test
c17081905d25        ubuntu              "bash"              2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                          mystifying_kalam
```

I would like to start the firewall-test container with a bash shell and this setting --cap-add=NET_ADMIN

The command i am trying does not work, it keep complaining about the latest version of this container...

```
sudo docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it firewall-test bash


Unable to find image 'firewall-test:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for firewall-test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The firewall-test container is based on the ubuntu one under it in the list.

How can i run this container with net-admin support so i can play around with iptables?

Thanks

Comment: A virtual machine would be a better match for this.  Usually in Docker the container system fully manages the network environment for you.

Comment: thanks, that helps me out

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with the syntax here. The form is 'docker run [-OPTIONS] [IMAGE NAME] {commands if you use options like -it or an entrypoint}'.
In your case it would be "docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it [IMAGE NAME] bash". First be sure that you have a 'firewall-test' image already build/downloaded.
In case you're using a Dockerfile image based, first build it. Or if you are using an image from hub.docker on something like that be sure the name is correct.

Good luck